# Sum of hypercubes modulo $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, congruences

Let $p$ be a prime number and $n$ a natural number. What is $\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} i^n$ modulo $p$ ?

If $p>2$ and $n$ is odd it's easy to see that the sum is zero, but I don't see how to tackle this in general.

Comment: Who is x and why are you talking about n ?

Comment: @mercio: sorry, hopefully the edits made it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g$ be a primitive root modulo $p$.
Then for every $1\leq i\leq p-1$ we have $i=g^{a_i}$ where $a_1,a_2,...,a_{p-1}$ is a rearrangement of the numbers $1,2,...,p-1$
So your sum is equal to $$g^{a_1\cdot n}+g^{a_2\cdot n}+...+g^{a_{p-1}\cdot n}=g^n+g^{2n}+...g^{(p-1)\cdot n}$$
which is equal to (using Fermat's little theorem) $$\frac{g^{np}-1}{g^n-1}-1\equiv\frac{g^n-1}{g^n-1}-1\equiv 0\pmod p$$

Comment: What if n is a multiple of p-1 ?

Comment: @mercio It does not matter and this can be seen in several ways.You can see that the fraction reduces to 1 modp again or you can see from the beginning that the sum is =0modp

Comment: Are you saying that (p-1)*1 = 0 (mod p) ?